# HashTable superclass as value

Tags: java, hashtable, subclass

I'm having some problems doing an HashTable in Java with an Object as value.
So, I have a superclass called "Bonus" and I got some subclasses called HammerBonus, BombBonus, etc.
I have created my HashTable like this:

```
private Hashtable<String, Bonus> hashBonusElement= new Hashtable<String, Bonus>();
```

But now I cant add any subclass as a value, for exemple:

```
hashBonusElement.put(Hammer.class.getSimpleName(), HammerBonus);
```

It says that "HammerBonuscannot be resolved to a variable".

I have tried somethings like "(Bonus)HammerBonus", "HammerBonus.class" but nothing works...
Is there anything that I can do for make it work?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Is `HammerBonus` an object of `HammerBonus` class? It's a compile time error. There is no variable with the name `HammerBonus`. It should like this `HammerBonus hb = new HammerBonus(); hashBonusElement.put(Hammer.class.getSimpleName(), hb);`

Comment: So I have to create variables first and then add them?

Comment: why can't be like that?

Comment: I see... I need to change some code then for dont have multiple instances of the same class but it worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you added the Class name as a value to the HashMap..

**try this**

```
hashBonusElement.put(Hammer.class.getSimpleName(), new HammerBonus());
```

will create a new instance of HammerBonus to add as a value to the HashMap.

Comment: Thank you... that worked... was that Braj was comment too...
Thank you :)

Comment: If your answer matched by any previous comment then it's a good practice to up-vote it. Rest is on your mood.

Comment: @Braj i never refreshed my page after i anwered

Comment: you can do it later not at the time of writing your answer.

Comment: Braj... I was about to ask you for post your answer since you solve it first I could mark your answer as the right answer